# About the class at IDE

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I have generated a wsdl class at salesforce. But I cannot find the class at ide. Even in add/Data component still cannot. Do anyone how to find this class in ide.

Comment: use the `Browse` feature

Answer (score 0):

Did you refresh sources from server, as it showed below?
[image]